# Determine the correct /dev/usb/lp*

Tags: linux, printing, usb

Is there a way to determine which printer uses which /dev/usb/lp* ? I'm building a system which should automatically allocate printers if reconnected. And I don't want to force assignment using udev rules. I can find the required device on the bus, but can't find it's /dev/usb/lp*.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
udevadm info -q all -n /dev/usb/lp1
```